# In hypothetic situation, Past vs Present

Tags: tense

Here's a sentences that I've made. But I'm not sure I'm right.

My girl friend lives healthily, so in a situation where we should choose a restaurant, we go to a restaurant selling healthy foods. So naturally,

> 1. I get to eat healthy foods more than I would if my girl friend were a person who **eats** whatever she **wants** to eat.
> 2. I get to eat healthy foods more than I would if my girl friend were a person who **ate** whatever she **wanted** to eat.

Point is in a hypothetic situation, do we have to use **all past tense** to phrase present unreal situation? So, which one is the right one?

Comment: Both forms are acceptable to my AmE ear, although we Americans tend to be less prolix: *....if my girlfriend ate whatever she wanted.*

Comment: To my BrE ear, both forms are also fine. The key I think is that you have shown your unreal/hypothetical situation in "I would if my girlfriend were..." and so the next part of the clause is more relaxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In speech (or writing representing speech) either sentence will be acceptable.**
*BUT*
In formal writing the verbs in the relative clause should **not** be 'sideshifted' into the modal past-tense form. This clause is not hypothetical or counterfactual but assertive: it describes a certain sort of person who actually exists. The sideshifted modal 'were' expresses the  hypotheticality/counterfactuality of your girlfriend being that sort of person.

> X = a person who eats whatever she wants to eat.
> I get to eat healthy foods more than I would if my girlfriend were X.

However, you *would* have to sideshift *eat* and *want* into the past-tense form if you couched this as an activity directly performed by your girlfriend herself:

> I get to eat healthy foods more than I would if my girlfriend **ate**  whatever she **wanted** to eat.

In you original sentences, the form on *want* and *eat* is governed by tense rather than modality; it is 'backshifted' for a past situation:

> Today I **get** to eat healthy foods more than I would if my girl friend were a person who **eats** whatever she **wants** to eat.
>
> When I was in college I **got** to eat healthy foods more than I **would have** if my girl friend **had been** a person who **ate** whatever she **wanted** to eat.

But this backshift may be overridden if it is clear from your discourse you still have the same girlfriend, with the same eating habits:

> Even when we were in college I got to eat healthy foods more than I would have if my girlfriend were a person who eats whatever she wants to eat.

Comment: I agree with this distinction you're making ("...If she were to take the pill that *makes* you small..") but when the verb is copular "were" it's not as clear-cut and the irrealis often spills over into the relative clause: "...if she were someone who *pops|popped* random pills..."

Comment: @TRomano Yeah, that *someone* is vaguer than the frank noun *person* and blurs the line between *she* and the popper. It's got a kind of hedginess that you encounter very often in conversational registers. But I think if you find yourself writing something like this in a formal register it's a red flag that you're getting a little bit too loose.